# "Would a general Languages.SE supersite ... be feasible?" on Area 51

Tags: discussion

I asked this on Area 51: [Would a general Languages.SE supersite (synchronized with the current language sites) be feasible?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29986/would-a-general-languages-se-site-be-feasible)  I thought I'd raise it to your attention, because it's likely of interest here.

I'm still not sure if it's a good idea, but I thought I'd just put it out there to think about.